# Deploying django by python manage.py runserver to production on VPS

Tags: python, django, django-deployment

I've bought a VPS for my django app. I've never ever before deployed django, or any other application. I've read a few tutorials on how to deploy django using apache and wsgi and some other options gunicorn, ngix. To me it all seems very frustrating and hard to understand. I was wondering what would happen if I deployed my application by changing debug to false, creating a database, plugging it in and then simply running python manage.py runserver my-ip. 
Is this a bad practice ?

Comment: There's a lot of hate here, but I think it's a valuable question - the documentation I've read doesn't explain why you need a web server, gunicorn etc, and since I can serve my dev server without one it's interesting to know what they are providing that is so necessary.

Comment: I also don't understand why no one can provide an adequate answer beyond "just don't". Has accepting dictums without understanding the underlying rationale ever been a good idea?

Comment: The main reason is that the Django server is not considered secure. Generally-speaking data needs protection even within a protected environment, which makes the manage.py runserver unsuitable for production.

Answer (score 6):

It is easy to learn how to deploy a Django project.

**At first,** you should know how to install `Apache` and `mod_wsgi`

if you use `Ubuntu`

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 libapache2-mod-wsgi
```

or `Fedora` (red hat) (without test)

```
yum install httpd mod_wsgi
```

**Then,** you should know how to associate Apache2 with your Django project

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAdmin example@example.com

    Alias /media/ /home/tu/blog/media/

    <Directory /home/tu/blog/media>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/tu/blog/blog/wsgi.py

    <Directory /path/to/django/project/wsgifile>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The sentence `WSGIScriptAlias` associate Apache2 configuration with your Django project
in Django `wsgi.py` file, you will see `project.settings` included, that is how it works

The following may be easy to understand how it works

***.conf --> wsgi.py --> settings.py --> urls.py and apps**

just search in Google like `ubuntu django server mod_wsgi` and learn it yourself!

Answer (score 3):

Do not do use the dev server in production. Just don't.

At the very least serve it off gunicorn:

```
$ pip install gunicorn
$ cd your_project
$ gunicorn project.wsgi  # gunicorn now runs locally on port 8000
```

And have nginx (or apache) as a reverse proxy:

```
server {
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
}
```

Deploying Django (just like any other application) is a world in and of itself, and mastering it takes time. But don't ever run the development server in production.

Comment: Could you please explain why I need gunicorn and nginx or apache? I take your word on it that I do, but I'd like to understand what they're providing me.

Comment: Why not use development server in production in very small scale scenarios? Add explanation please. See http://serverfault.com/q/717568/134848.

Comment: Please provide explanation why not to use dev server in production?

Comment: @Ricky - from the Django docs: "DO NOT USE THIS SERVER IN A PRODUCTION SETTING. It has not gone through security audits or performance tests."

Comment: Well, you would only need nginx as a reverse proxy if you serve static files, in case your django app is an API, you only would need gunicorn.